# How to obtain standard error of cumulative effect of binary variable in distributed lag model?

Tags: r, time-series, meta-analysis, distributed-lag

In distributed lag non-linear model, the author used meta-anlysis to get the summarized statistic of cumulative effect.

However, it can only to apply numeric function. If I fit the binary variable with `dlnm`, then `crosspred` function cannot be used to obtain the estimate of standard error. Is there anyway to do it?

Comment: You reference an article, can you link/reference it?